# Bound on the size of the solution to $u_{t} - \Delta u - u \leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $B$ denote the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and let $u$ be a smooth function such that $u_{t} - \Delta u - u \leq 0$ in $U_{T}:= B \times (0, T]$ and $u = 1$ on the parabolic boundary (that is, on $B \times \{t = 0\} \cup \partial B \times (0, T]$).

Letting $w := e^{-t}u$ and applying the maximum principle to $w$ gives that $\max_{U_{T}} w = 1$ which implies that $1 \leq u \leq e^{T}$ in $U_{T}$. Is this bound sharp? That is, can one decrease the $e^{T}$ bound?

Answer (score 1):

This bound is not sharp. Indeed, $w$ is majorized by the solution of the diffusion equation with boundary condition $w(x,t)=e^{-t}$ on the boundary. In particular, $w$ is strictly less than $1$ for all times $t>0$, and therefore $u(x,t)<e^t$.

In order to produce the sharp bound, you have to solve the diffusion equation $v_t-\Delta v=0$ with $v(x,t)=e^{-t}$ on the parabolic boundary. This is a pretty tedious task without an explicit result. One could approach it by writing $v(x,t)=e^{-t} + v_0(x,t)$ where $v_0$ has homogeneous boundary conditions and satisfies the nonhomogeneous PDE $(v_0)_t -\Delta v_0 = e^{-t}$. So, $v_0$ can be written as an integral involving the Dirichlet heat kernel for the unit ball. I don't know if there's an explicit formula for this heat kernel.